# Nested sudoku in entrance exam

Tags: logical-deduction, sudoku, grid-deduction

My university (Keio university in Japan) set this question in 2013's entrance exam. The red boxes include numbers from 1 to 9.
[image]

What's the solution for this sudoku?

Comment: Please change the title as per my suggestion to ***"Overlapping-constraint 3x3;2x2 sudoku..."*** It's more explicit and clear. Otherwise it just sounds like yet another 3x3 sudoku question, which it isn't. The point is the 2x2 constraints overlap, but on a different grid.

Comment: @smci why 2x2?  There is no 2x2 constraint

Comment: Counter-intuitively, the red boxes actually make it easier rather than harder

Comment: @Kwvin: there **is** a 2x2 constraint; it's the red boxes; they are conceptually a separate 2x2 grid, (but partially overlapping with the 3x3 grid). That's why I said ***"Overlapping-constraint 3x3;2x2 sudoku..."***

Comment: @smci these are commonly known as windoku or hyper sudoku.

Comment: @paramesis. Thanks, didn't know. Please edit improve the title as they kept rejecting my suggestions.

Comment: @smci The red boxes are another 3x3 constraint

Comment: @Kevin: ah my mistake. [The red boxes and non-red areas do indeed form a separate 3x3 grid](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/Windoku_Strategy) as explained by that link. Wasn't obvious until I read that explanation. Disregard my previous comments.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Final solution

> [image: Ta-da!]

### Step-by-step explanation

- In the upper right red square, there's only one possible position for 7.
- In the lower right red square, there's only one possible position for 5.
- In the seventh row, there's only one possible position for 7.
- In the eighth row, there's only one possible position for 6.
- In the second row, there's only one possible position for 3.

> [image: first steps]

- In the eighth column, there's only one possible position for 3.
- In the bottom middle 3x3 box, there's only one possible position for 3.
- In the seventh row, there's only one possible position for 5, then only one for 4, then only 3 is left.
- In the lower right red square, there's only one possible position for 2, then only 1 is left.
- Now only 1 is left in the bottom right 3x3 box.

> [image: next steps]

- In the eighth row, there's only one possible position for 7, then only one for 8, then only 4 is left.
- Now only 2 is left in the bottom left 3x3 box.
- In the first column, there's only one possible position for 5, then only one for 1, then only 6 is left.
- In the top left 3x3 box, there's only one possible position for 7.

> [image: filling in bottom and left]

- In the lower left red square, there's only one possible position for 6, then only 4 is left.
- In the second column, there's only one possible position for 1, then only one for 2, then only 5 is left.
- In the middle left 3x3 box, there's only one possible position for 3, then only 6 is left.
- In the sixth row, there's only one possible position for 2, then only 8 is left.

> [image: getting there ...]

- In the ninth column, there's only one possible position for 7, then only 8 is left.
- In the fifth row, there's only one possible position for 6.
- In the seventh column, there's only one possible position for 1, then only 8 is left.
- Now only 2 is left in the top right 3x3 box.

> [image: more and more]

- In the upper left red square, there's only one possible position for 8, then only one for 5, then only 4 is left.
- Now only 4 is left in the third row.
- In the upper right red square, there's only one possible position for 2, then only one for 1, then only 3 is left.
- Now only 4 is left in the fourth row and in the eighth column.
- Now only 1 is left in the fifth row, and only 7 in the second row.

> [image: Now we're basically done]

And from there it's easy to get the final solution.